# Scraping Multiple Pages On A Website

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a list of all the coaching instiututes on thsi URL:
https://www.sulekha.com/entrance-exam-coaching/delhi

The following is my Python code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request
import urlopen as uReq
from bs4
import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.sulekha.com/entrance-exam-coaching/delhi'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close() x

page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")


insti = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "list-title"})

filename = "entrance_institutes.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Institute \n"
f.write(headers)

for ins in insti:
    ins_name = ins.div.a["title"]

f.write(ins_name + "\n")

f.close()
```

This code runs fine. Attached is the image of the csv it generates. How should I go about scraping all the listings one page after the other ?

Thanks

[Output csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRTW8.png)

Comment: I think your current code is not saving all the institutes' names even from one single page, right? Shouldn't your `f.write` statement be inside the `for` loop?

Comment: The code runs fine.. I am extremely new to this. What i need to understand is how do I move to the next page.. ? This code scraps the names of 10 institutes on page one.. What do I need to do/learn to be able to make the program automatically traverse all the pages and keep scraping the names onto a csv file.

Comment: going through separate pages requires you to rin the same loop over different URLs. so now you have to find out which URLs that are. maybe there's a simple structure to them, or you could scrape them form the page itself, or perhaps you could simply 'click' a next button in the pagination links with a library that allows that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean. If you're asking how to fix the bug in your code then you need to change your loop to:

```
for ins in insti:
    ins_name = ins.div.a["title"]
    f.write(ins_name + "\n")
```

As your code is you loop through the everything and write the last one due to the write not being in the loop.

However if you're asking how to take that list and then scrap those then that's more involved and for starters you need to save the URL rather than the title but I'm going to leave the rest to you because that kind of sounds like homework.